# Access PDF files in my app IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3

**Ultimate Goal: upload pdf to AWS S3 server**

*Where i am now:*

I've been developing on IOS for over a month now and one thing it lacks is access to a simple file management system. Coming off of Android I could simply open a view which would let me access the downloads, photos, Google Drive, etc. On Android its simple, I choose the PDF I want to upload and that's it. On IOS I have yet to find a way to access PDF's or files. Only thing that works so far is viewing photos and videos and choosing one of them to upload.

> is there a way to access a PDF on an IPad/IPhone to upload to an AWS S3 server?

My code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}







NSArray *filePathsArray;

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
 }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{

    if ([filePathsArray count] > 0){
        return [filePathsArray count];
     }else{
         return 1;
     }
}

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView          cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell    alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
 }




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *pdfPicked = cell.textLabel.text;

    NSLog(@"PDF is: %@", pdfPicked);
 }

@end
```

This code will look through the files in the documents folder and display the file path of each file in a UITableView. If i add a PDF to the documents folder then i can see it on the table view but apparently you cannot access the documents folder on an actual IPhone or IPad.

Comment: Clarify your issue. Where is the problem? Where do you attempt to access the file?

Answer (score 0):

you can use document picker to pick documents from icloud and outside app's sandbox.

you can get reference of document picker here [DocumentPicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

for document picker demo you can click on [github](https://github.com/shinobicontrols/iOS8-day-by-day/blob/master/28-document-picker/28-document-picker.md)